# div does not cover full width

Tags: php, html, css

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    <title>Golden Ratio</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
    .wrapper {
    background-color:#DFE2DB;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 1080px;   
 border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #888888;
    }
    .banner{
    border: 5px solid #558C89;
    height: 200px;
    }
    .content_area{
    float:left;
    width:750px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    height:400px; 
    border: 2px solid #D9853B;
    }
    .sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #2B2B2B;
    }
    footer{
    clear:both;
     width:auto;
    color:#fff;
    height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    text-shadow:0.1em 0.1em #E9E581;
    text-align:center;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    }
    .announcement_section{
    height:40px;
    border: 2px solid #4499cc;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
 display: none;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
    }
    #nav ul{
 background: #efefef; 
 background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 padding: 0 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;  
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
    }
     #nav ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: ;
    }
    #nav ul li {
 float: left;
     }
    #nav ul li:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
      }
      #nav ul li:hover a {
   color: #fff;
      }
 
      #nav ul li a {
  display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
      }
      #nav ul ul {
   background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
   position: absolute; top: 100%;
      }
      #nav ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
        }
        #nav ul ul li a {
   padding: 15px 40px;
   color: #fff;
        } 
        #nav ul ul li a:hover {
   background: #6699aa;
        }
        #nav ul ul ul {
     position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
        }

        </style>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#bbccdd">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="banner">
        <h1>banner here</h1>

         </div>
         <div id="nav">
      <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Registration</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Registration FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How to register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register now</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">register1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">register1</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">register2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">register2</a></li>
   </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
           </div>


           <div class="content_area">
           <h1>content area</h1>

           </div>
           <div class="sidebar">
           <h1>News here</h1>

           </div>
           <footer>  
            <p>All rights reserved</p>
           </footer>
           </div>
           </body>
           </html>
```

My code as above has one problem: my navigation bar does not extend to cover the full width but everything else works fine. what might be the problem. I have tried width:100% on the nav but seems not work. how do i fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope You want this.

```css
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
background-color:#DFE2DB;   
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;  
width: 1080px;   
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #888888;
}
.banner{
border: 5px solid #558C89;
height: 200px;
}

.content_area{
float:left;
width:750px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
padding: 10px;
height:400px; 
border: 2px solid #D9853B;
}
.sidebar{
float:right;
width:250px;
height:400px;
margin: 20px 10px;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid #2B2B2B;
}
footer{
clear:both;
 width:auto;
color:#fff;
height:40px;
padding:10px;
text-shadow:0.1em 0.1em #E9E581;
text-align:center;
border: 3px solid #fff;
}
.announcement_section{
height:40px;
border: 2px solid #4499cc;
}

#nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul{
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
width:100%;
padding:0px !important;
}
 #nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: ;
}
#nav ul li {
float: left;
 }
#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
  }
  #nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
  }

  #nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
  }
  #nav ul ul {
  background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
  width:auto !important;
  }
  #nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
    }
    #nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
    #nav ul ul li a:hover {
        background: #6699aa;
    }
    #nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#bbccdd">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="banner">
    <h1>banner here</h1>

     </div>
     <div id="nav">
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Registration</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Registration FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How to register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Register now</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">register1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">register1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">register2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">register2</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>


       <div class="content_area">
       <h1>content area</h1>

       </div>
       <div class="sidebar">
       <h1>News here</h1>

       </div>
       <footer>  
        <p>All rights reserved</p>
       </footer>
       </div>
       </body>
```

Comment: what exactly was the fix? dont want to make the same mistake again

Comment: your #nav ul was not width of 100% so i added width 100% to your parent ul and then again your child ul was also taking width 100% so i make it width auto. hope you got it .